# How to print a Function<A,B>?

Tags: java

I would like to create a central logger class that logs messages like:

> Couldn't find a record of type MyClass when searching for field
> MyField

Currently, I have this piece of code:

```
public static <T, A, B> String logNotFound(final Class<T> type, String field) {
    return String.format(DATA_NOT_FOUND, type.getSimpleName(), field);
}
```

And I call it like:

```
Optional<Person> person = findPersonByLastName("Smith");
if (person.isEmpty()) logNotFound(Person.class, "lastName");
```

However, I don't quite like passing a string to the field name. I would like to call the log method as

```
logNotFound(Person.class, Person::getLastName)
```

passing a Function<A,B> as parameter. I expect a message like

> Couldn't find a record of type Person when searching for field > Person::getLastName

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't.  Sorry.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you are wrong, there is a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be XY problem: you actually need to log errors in convenient way, but do not know how to refer class fields in code... There are two options:

1. lombok: [@FieldNameConstants](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants) - [there are some issues](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2090)
2. implement [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) which will generate metamodel for your classes (or if you are on HBN you may use existing one: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-metamodel/)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, use (or analyze the source code and implement it in your way) [safety-mirror](https://github.com/Hervian/safety-mirror) library:

```java
assertEquals("isEmpty", Fun.getName(String::isEmpty));
```

Here you read more details - [Printing debug info on errors with java 8 lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860875/printing-debug-info-on-errors-with-java-8-lambda-expressions/21879031#21879031)