# How to get the method name that is passed as a lambda parameter in Java

Tags: java, reflection

For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyRPC {
    Object execute(Object input);
}

public class MyImpl{
    public Object rpc1(Object input) {
        System.out.Println(input)
        return 100;
    }

    public static Object invokeRpc(MyRPC rpc, Object input) {
        // TODO: How can I get the name of the method passed in, like "rpc1" or "MyImpl::rpc1" here?
        return rpc.execute(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyWfImpl myc = new MyWfImpl();
        invokeRpc(myc::rpc1, 1)
    }
}
```

In `invokeRpc`, How can I get the rpc name like "rpc1" or "MyImpl::rpc1"?

Comment: It's impossible to get that.

Comment: you can set a breakpoint (or print stacktrace) to see the call hierarchy....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing debug info on errors with java 8 lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860875/printing-debug-info-on-errors-with-java-8-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Thanks. I think that question is related yeah. But not quite exactly. I think even my problem is more on Java reflection and looks like there is no solution due to the limitation of Java lambda. But this may change in the future (hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.  Lambdas do not carry that information in a way that you can access.

Comment: Unless the lambda is serializable...

Answer (score 2):

This is doable, but only via a hack, so there's no guarantee it will work on each VM.

With that out of the way, here's how to do it:

**1.** Make your functional interface extend `Serializable`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyRPC extends Serializable {
    Object execute(Object input);
}
```

Its instances will now have an internal method called `writeReplace` that can be used to extract a `SerializedLambda` that will contain metadata.

**2.** Extract the class/method info from `SerializedLambda` (you can add the code to some utility class, or the functional interface itself):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyRPC extends Serializable {
    Object execute(Object input);
    
    default SerializedLambda serialized() {
        try {
            Method replaceMethod = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
            replaceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            return (SerializedLambda) replaceMethod.invoke(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    default String getImplClassName() {
        return serialized().getImplClass().replaceAll("/", ".");
    }

    default String getImplMethodName() {
        return serialized().getImplMethodName();
    }
}
```

**3.** Enjoy the fruits of your hackery:

```
public static Object invokeRpc(MyRPC rpc, Object input) {
    System.out.println(rpc.getImplMethodName()); //
    return rpc.execute(input);
}
```