# Get class and static method name referred by lambda

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible to programatically read class and static method name referred by lambda? For example:

```
public class Testing {

interface Generic { void call(); }

static public void method1() {
    System.out.println("In method1");
}

static public void method2() {
    System.out.println("In method2");
}

public void test() {
    Generic g1 = () -> Testing.method1();
    Generic g2 = () -> Testing.method2();

    g1.call();
    g2.call();

    // System.out.println("g1 -> " + getLambdaReference(g1))
}
```

I would like to somehow read that `g1` is pointing to `Testing.method1` and `g2` is pointing to `Test.method2`.

Comment: But `g1` isn't "pointing to `Testing.method1`". What if you had `Generic g1 = () -> { Testing.method1(); Testing.method2(); };`?

Comment: Sure, I'm interested in this specific case and I'm wondering is there any direct or indirect way to try figure it out.

Comment: Nope. That's not possible.

Comment: Note that even with a method-reference `Generic g1 = Testing::method1;`, [you couldn't do it anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845393/1743880).

Comment: `g1` in your case is probably really `Generic$$lambda1` or something close to that - it's really not a reference but an anonymous inner class (_at runtime_) which forwards the call to desired method. So no, you can't get that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such reference. Those lambda functions are just Lambdas executing some codes.

If those approachs are possible, then how can you deal with

`Generics g = ()->1+2;`

or any other *just expressions*?

Comment: Is there a way to get source of lambda code into a String?

Comment: Nope. That's not possible.

Comment: @aioobe How? Plz give me an example.

Comment: @JunyoungClareJang, I can't give you an example of something that's impossible.

Comment: @aioobe Sorry, i misread your comment. However, why did you add redundant comment? Is it to Lukasz? I misread your comment because of this point.

Comment: Lukasz asked if it was possible to get the source of lambda code as a String. I answered no. I don't see what's redundant about that.