# Converting method call to the java.lang.reflect.Method object of that method

Tags: java, generics

I am struggling trying to convert a 'method call' to the 'method object' of that method.

I have:

```
someClassInstance.someInstanceMethod(new Function<Person, Method>() {
     @Override
     public Method apply(Person p) {
         return p.getAge(); // I want to convert 'p.getAge()' to the the method of 'getAge'
     }
 });
```

I know I can simplify this with lambda's but I thought this would make what I want to do more clear.

p.getAge()
currently returns an 'int', but I want it to return the 'Method object' of 'getAge()'.
What I Mean by the 'Method object' is this:

```
 Method method = Person.class.getMethod("getAge"); // I basically want to return this.
```

The reason for this is, I'm building my own little framework to gain experience and letting the user use:

```
someClassInstance.someInstanceObject((Function<Person, Method>) o -> o.getAge());
```

Seems more user friendly.

NOTE: I do have my own interface of 'Function' that does not take 'Method' as a second generic type so the user only has to type:

```
someClassInstance.<Person>someInstanceMethod(o -> o.getAge());
```

Comment: Indeed I need the getAge to return itself, this is because, getAge represents a Getter method for the property 'age', and via the method object I want to get the property 'age'.

Comment: I don't want to execute the method, when I have the method I will get the property 'private int age' of that method. (if the passed method is a getter-method).

Comment: method.getName() will return a String 'getAge'. The framework will rely on correctly specifying the naming conventions of getter method (name of the property with 'get' prefix or 'is' prefix for booleans) and thus I can extract 'age' from 'getAge' and use java reflections to get the property 'age'

Comment: Yes the reason I want to do it this was, Fleunt API for Entity Framework (C#) uses a similar approach for explicitly specifying relations between entities (classes). and I just want to recreate that approach and I have been trying to do so for the past few days but I haven't succeeded. Therefore my question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some more days I finally found an answer, somewhere in the comments of an old stack overflow question, I found this link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745127/3478229
```

This answer from another question links to a library written by 'Benji Weber' this library used 'cglib' to create proxy objects to get the method of a Function<T, U>.

Meaning:

```
 someMethod(Person::getAge) //returns a String 'age'.
```